# PostgreSql search– showing text excerpts that match query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got a Rails application where users can post blog articles and search through the articles.

In the search results, is there an easy way to show the excerpts of the articles that match the word(s) in the query?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.description_search(query)
    if query.present?
      where("description @@ ?", query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

For example, I'd like to extract something like "...John jumps the shark on a sunny..." from the following example article if I was searching for "shark" across all articles:

> John jumps the bed.  John jumps the bed.  John jumps the bed.  John
>   jumps the bed.  John jumps the bed.  John jumps the bed.  John jumps
>   the bed.  John jumps the bed.  John jumps the bed.  ***John jumps the
>   shark on a sunny day.***  John jumps the bed.

Comment: Write some code about what you are trying to do and what you have done till now?

Comment: @techdreams Ok, I added the example code.

Answer (score -1):

To get excerpt ie a brief data
you can do the following

```
@blogs=Blog.where("coloumn like ?",params[:q])
@blogs.each do |blog|
puts blog.article.truncate(10) // this line will truncate text after 10 characters, so u will get a brief data
end
```

Comment: Will this always show where the keyword matched the article?  It seems like it will only take the first 10 characters.  If the keyword was found in the article after the first 10 characters, then this seems like it wouldn't work, right?

Comment: it will match the keyword matched in the blog's column,
 here you seems to confuser with truncate function , well thr result will consist of lot of characters so this function will replace the text after 10 characters with ... eg ..
john jumps the bed=> john jump.....

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!  I updated the question to show that if "shark" is the keyword, how can I return the 10 characters around "shark"?  I think `blog.article.truncate(10)` will only return the first 10 characters.

Comment: u means like if there is a sentence 

john's boat is above the shark's group ??

u need the work john's boat and group??

Comment: Yes, if "shark" is around character 100, then I'd like to extract characters 90-110.  I'm wondering if PostgreSQL has anything automatic built in to do this.  I can do it manually for each search result, but that will slow things down.  Does PostgreSQL have anything built in?

Comment: Yes in postgres you can use LIKE Clause 

example:
User.where('name LIKE ?', '%' + query + '%')